# Get image url with https instead of http

Tags: 8, media, uri

When I use file_create_url it return url with http instead of https.

Code Snippet:

```
$desimg = file_create_url($node->field_image->entity->getFileUri());
```

Due to which i m getting warning like below

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/test/test_M_01.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

I'm missing something?

Comment: Either you have to solve the problem that the client sees HTTPS and Drupal sees HTTP, probably caused by a CDN, or use a relative path for the image, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/function/file_url_transform_relative/8.6.x.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue of reverse proxy, read the below article this may solve your problem

https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/2842049